# Calling a wsdl service from a microservice c#

Tags: c#, wsdl, microservices, asp.net-core-6.0

How do I call a WSDL service at runtime in C# and ASP.NET Core 6.0 inside a micro service?

I have tried with `HttpClient`, other solutions like channel factory but they have not solved the problem.

```
private static async Task LlamadaServicioAsync()
{
    string wsdlUrl = "http://localhost/SCTSBJAX/ServiciosVEXJx?wsdl";
    string operationName = "ConsultarSaldosCobros";
    string soapAction = "http://localhost:7031/ConsultarSaldosCobros/";
    string requestBody = "<cce:ConsultaCobroReq><sesionReq><sesionId>57301</sesionId><userId>8</userId><hashSesion>008B5AAD0643AE56C721CDF71AFE7D82A04F6C95031B650EA888FD7D512E9C95</hashSesion><codTran>1</codTran><codigoCanal>1</codigoCanal></sesionReq><servicioAdq><codigoEmpresaAdq>1</codigoEmpresaAdq><codigoAplicacionAdq>VEX</codigoAplicacionAdq><codigoServicioAdq>6</codigoServicioAdq><codigoCanalAdq>1201</codigoCanalAdq><referenciaAdquiriente>54214089</referenciaAdquiriente><fechaAdquiriente>2016-02-20T09:56:29-05:00</fechaAdquiriente><codigoComercio>0990858322001PG041</codigoComercio><codigoTerminal>123</codigoTerminal></servicioAdq><productoReq><codigoInstitucion>408</codigoInstitucion><codAplProducto>SER</codAplProducto><codigoProducto>386</codigoProducto><camposAdicionales>\"{\"campos\\\":[{\"codigo\":\"Tipo Identificacion\",\"valor\":\"CEDULA\",\"requerido\":\"M\"},{\"codigo\":\"Identificacion\",\"valor\":\"1304837162\",\"requerido\":\"M\"}]}\"</camposAdicionales></productoReq><codigoInstitucionAut>406</codigoInstitucionAut></cce:ConsultaCobroReq></cce:ConsultarSaldosCobro>";

    await CallWebService(wsdlUrl, operationName, soapAction, requestBody);
}

public static async Task CallWebService(string wsdlUrl, string operationName, string soapAction, string requestBody)
{
    // Download the WSDL file
    string wsdl = await DownloadWsdl(wsdlUrl);

    // Create a binding and endpoint address
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(wsdlUrl);

    // Create a channel factory
    ChannelFactory<IClientChannel> factory = new ChannelFactory<IClientChannel>(binding, endpointAddress);

    // Create a message
    Message requestMessage = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, soapAction, new StringReader(requestBody));

    // Create a channel
    IClientChannel channel = factory.CreateChannel();

    try
    {
        // Open the channel
        channel.Open();

        // Send the request and get the response
        Message responseMessage = await channel.RequestAsync(requestMessage);

        // Process the response
        using (XmlReader reader = responseMessage.GetReaderAtBodyContents())
        {
            // Read the response body
            XmlDocument responseXml = new XmlDocument();
            responseXml.Load(reader);

            // Process the response XML as needed
            Console.WriteLine(responseXml.OuterXml);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close the channel
        if (channel.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
        {
            channel.Abort();
        }
        else
        {
            channel.Close();
        }

        // Close the factory
        factory.Close();
    }
}
```

Actually I have a soap service has a method `ConsultarSaldosCobros` and a request, I need call in execution time. If I add a service reference, it works fine, but the address site changes according to the environment, so I need use an environment variable for the address, and execution reads the variable and calls the method.

Comment: Does it have a WSDL file to generate the corresponding C# code? Or are you asking how to call it using HttpClient?

Comment: actually i have a soap service has a method ConsultarSaldosCobros and a request, i need call in execution time, actually if i add a service reference works fine, but the addres site changes according to the environment. so i need put a environment variable the address, and execution read the variable and call the method.

Comment: You should  be able to specify it in your App.config file, change per environment. If you want to do it through Environment variables to change your root URL you can do that too

Answer (score 0):

The code was:

```
string direccion = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(StringHandler.LOGIN_URL);

  using HttpContent content = new StringContent(text, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
  using HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Post, direccion);
  request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", direccion);
  request.Content = content;
  using HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
  string respuesta  = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```